# Problem with evaluating the exact value of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 \cos(\ln(x)) \, dx$

I was able to evaluate the improper integral which is:

$$\frac{x\left(\sin \ln x + \cos \ln x\right)}{2}$$

I was using the substitution $u = \ln x$, and afterward I did integration by parts twice and got the result:

$$\frac{e^u\left( \sin(u) + \cos(u) \right)}{2}$$

Applying $x=1$ we get $u = 0$ and applying $x=0$ we get $u=-\infty$.

So how can it be calculated?

Comment: So what exactly do you want to evaluate? Do you wish to simplify the result you've got?

Comment: The value of the integral between $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says you get approximately 0.5

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28ln%28x%29%29+from+0+to+1+

I guess it considered the terms for your split improper integral to be 1/2 * 1 - 1/2 * 0 by inputting 1 and 0 respectively and for some reason disregarding the problems which arise when you input zero for the natural log..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

$$\begin{align}
u &= \ln(x) \implies e^{u}du = dx \\
x &= 0 \implies u = -\infty \\
x &= 1 \implies u = 0
\end{align}$$

Hence, you get

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\cos(u) du$$

Integrating by parts twice, first with $v = e^{u}$, $w' = \cos(u)$ and secondly with $v = e^{u}$, $w' = \sin(u)$

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\cos(u) du \\
&= e^{u}\sin(u) \biggr|_{-\infty}^{0} - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\sin(u) du \\
&= 0 - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\sin(u) du \\
&= -\bigg[ -e^{u}\cos(u)\biggr|_{-\infty}^{0} +  \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\cos(u) du \biggr] \\
&= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u}\cos(u) du \\
&= 1 - I
\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align}
I &= 1 - I \\
\implies I &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align}$$

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+cos%28lnx%29+dx%2C+x%3D0%2C+x%3D1) gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Mattos

Comment: @AlonAlon Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} -\frac{x}{2}\leq \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x\sin(\ln(x))}{2}\leq \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{2}
$$

Works also for $x\cos(\ln(x))$.

Comment: Hey Jean, would you mind replying my comment:http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1166430/188391