# Investigate the convergence of $\int_0^\infty (-1)^\left[{x^2}\right] \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Investigate the convergence of $\int_0^\infty (-1)^\left[{x^2}\right] \, dx$, where $[x]$ is the floor function

I'd be glad for a guidance.

Comment: Perhaps it will help to note:$(-1)^{x^2} = e^{i \pi x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(-1)^{[x^2]}=(-1)^n,\quad \sqrt n\le x<\sqrt{n+1}.
$$
Since $\bigl|(-1)^{[x^2]}\bigr|=1$, the integral does not converge absolutely.

$$
\int_0^\infty (-1)^{[x^2]}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n).
$$
Use Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Why is true that $(-1)^{[x^2]}=(-1)^n$?

Comment: @AlonAlon because $[x^2]$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The floor function applied to $x^2$ doesn't affect the logic of this answer, so I won't bother writing it (it also wasn't in the original formulation of the question).
$$\int_0^\infty (-1)^{x^2} \, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{i \pi x^2} \, dx$$
The absolute value of $e^{i \pi x^2}$ is a monotone $1$. Since convergence first requires absolute convergence, this integral cannot converge.

If you're still confused, you could think of it like this: if the term in the integral doesn't tend toward zero for increasing $x$, then there's no hope for the integral to converge because:
$$\exists \epsilon : |e^{i \pi x^2}| > \epsilon \quad \forall x \in \mathbb [0,\infty)$$$$(\text{$e^{i\pi x^2}$ not tending to $0$})$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\int_0^b|e^{i\pi x^2}| \, dx > b \cdot \epsilon $$$$(\text{Integral of absolute value not tending to $0$})$$
For increasing $b$, this lower bound of the limit $\int_0^\infty | e^{i\pi x^2} | \, dx$ becomes arbitrarily large. Thus the integral does not converge absolutely and in turn cannot converge (normally).